# Vaadin TwinColSelect filter only one column

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a TwinColSelect and a Textfield that I use to filter the content of the table, it works great, but the problem is that the filter filters the content of both columnos of the TwinColSelect, and I would like to know if it is possible that it only affects to the left column.

My code right now looks like this:

```
    final TwinColSelect select = new TwinColSelect();
    select.setItemCaptionPropertyId(PersistenceLoinc.CORPUS_NOMBRE);

    TextField filtro = new TextField();

    filtro.addTextChangeListener(new TextChangeListener() {


        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        SimpleStringFilter filter = null;

        @Override
        public void textChange(TextChangeEvent event) {
            Filterable f = (Filterable) select.getContainerDataSource();

            if (filter != null) {
                f.removeContainerFilter(filter);
            }
            filter = new SimpleStringFilter(select.getItemCaptionPropertyId(), event.getText(), true, false);
            f.addContainerFilter(filter);
        }
    });
```

Thanks,
Cris.

Comment: The only way would be to build a filter which does NOT filter the items already in the assigned list

Comment: @AndréSchild hmm, nice idea, man, nice idea, indeed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I followed the suggestion from @andreSchild in the comments section of the question, and developed the following class that works perfectly:

```
public class TwinColSelectStringFilter implements Container.Filter {

final SimpleStringFilter spf;
final TwinColSelect select;
final Object propertyId;

public TwinColSelectStringFilter(Object propertyId, String filterString, boolean ignoreCase, boolean onlyMatchPrefix, TwinColSelect select) {
    spf = new SimpleStringFilter(propertyId, filterString, ignoreCase, onlyMatchPrefix);
    this.select = select;
    this.propertyId=propertyId;
}

@Override
public boolean passesFilter(Object itemId, Item item) throws UnsupportedOperationException {
    if(select.getValue() != null && (select.getValue() instanceof Collection)) {
        if (((Collection<Integer>) select.getValue()).contains(itemId)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return spf.passesFilter(itemId, item);
}

@Override
public boolean appliesToProperty(Object propertyId) {
    return spf.appliesToProperty(propertyId);
}
```

}